# pgAdmin4 "Unauthorized" error

Tags: firefox, postgresql, pgadmin

I am using kUbuntu 18.04(bionic) on my local machine and I installed postgresql11 and pgadmin4 step by step from this guide https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt. And when i start pgAdmin4  firefox gives me this message:

Unauthorized

The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL requested. You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g. a bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required.

Can someone tell me what I did wrong or what else should I configure

Comment: Did you authorize access from other than localhost (127.0.0.1)?

Comment: No I didn't. I just installed it and run it

Answer (score 4):

What is happening is that when you start it and opens your browser, the ?key=xxx is lost. I copied mine from the startup log file in:

```
~/.pgAdmin4.startup.log
```

It should look something like this:

```
http://127.0.0.1:38485/?key=f687289c-62ca-4d64-a425-1b45ccee83d5
```

Comment: This worked for me! Visualizing the "~/.pgAdmin4.startup.log" file provides the port number and the key.

Answer (score 0):

1. In postgresql.conf add `listen_addresses = '*'` on the last line.
2. In `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf` add a new line:

   ```
   host all all YOUR_IP_ADDRESS/32 md5
   ```
3. Restart the service:

   ```
   sudo service postgresql restart
   ```

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Can the problem be between the pgadmin server and the browser(browser doesn't give key to the web server of the pgAdmin) and then triggers this reaction

Comment: Is pgAdmin4 deployed in a server mode?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I have windows 10 and installed it there too. When I run the Icon of pgAddmin4, it opens the browser and in the address bar it puts some key(I don't know where is configured "127.0.0.1:51138/?key=5ab2d258-7b31-411c-80f0-4137ad5d0e5f") and it works peferctly fine.

Comment: So, you are not getting the unauthorized error anymore?